# i have a problem while installing dotnet sdk on linux ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core

i have a little problem i recently updated my pc to ubuntu 20.04 and i have a problem installing dotnet-sdk thing from [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1910#troubleshoot-the-package-manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1910#troubleshoot-the-package-managerhttps://) and when i reach to `sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1` it gives me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dotnet-sdk-3.1 : Depends: dotnet-runtime-3.1 (>= 3.1.3) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 (>= 3.1.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i was using pop os 19.10 before but installing dotnet sdk wasnt a problem so for the linux users out there any help?

Comment: Microsoft hasn't yet announced support for Ubuntu 20.04, so you might have to wait for a few days.

Comment: I'd suggest asking on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution at the end of this Github topic.
Then I used the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gpg
wget O- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o microsoft.asc.gpg

sudo mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/

wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.10/prod.list

sudo mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list

sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg

sudo chown root:root /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list

sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/17638

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiaZO.png)

Comment: it is still giving me the same problem